# Can css positon block off-center with fixed ratio, like 1/3 left 2/3 right?

Tags: html, css

I have a web page with a form centered on the page. Easy enough: the form is "margin: 0px auto".

Now the client says they want a picture behind it and the form skewed to the left, with about 1/3 of the available space on the left and 2/3 on the right.

I can't hard-code the number of pixels because I don't know the width of the screen, and I only sort-of know the width of the form. The form presently has "width: 100%; max-width: 920px;" I may have to change that so at least some of the form will show on either side.

But okay, I can center with margin "auto", but how do I "off-center"? Is there a way to say to put 1/3 of the available space on the left and 2/3 on the right? I don't know a way to say that.

Comment: This seems familiar to a question I answered the other day - does this layout held guide you at all? http://stackoverflow.com/a/32272889/954940

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can simply use a margin and a transform:

```css
div {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  background: purple;
  margin-left: 33%;
  transform: translateX(-50%);
}
```

```html
<div></div>
```

Comment: Beat me to it +1, although I would mention `calc(100% / 3)` for that extra precision ;)

Comment: @jaunt If that precision mattered you could just as well type out `33.33%`. The former gives 214.641px and using calc gives 214.656px in the above example so the difference is practically nonexistent at that point and you save the browser a calc call.

Comment: @Nit True, but (ignoring the max-width) with larger screen resolutions there could be a few pixels in it. For example 6k resolution monitors will have differences - albeit insignificant compared to the resolution. (`6144px/3 = 2048px `and `6144px*0.33=2027.52px`). Granted your proposed `33.33%` would give 2047.7952px, which would round up to the correct 2048px. But let's assume that, inevitably, we get higher resolution monitors in the future. Why not prepare for that now?

Comment: @jaunt Mostly because using calc like that is just silly. Secondly because this will actually matter so rarely that if it's ever a point of concern you'll be sure to pay separate attention to it.

Comment: @nit Well, for 1/100 of 1% to add up to 1 pixel would require a screen resolution of 10,000 pixels, which is well beyond any screen I've ever used. And in a case like this, where we're talking about centering and off-centering, an error of 0.01% would be unlikely to be noticeable by the human eye. That said, I have run into cases where this sort of error compounded. Like I once had a couple of buttons to increase or decrease font size by some fixed percentage each time you clicked "+" or "-", and I got into trouble if you kept going up and down that errors would accumulate.

Comment: @Jay That simply sounds like bad programming.

Comment: @nit If you define "didn't give the right answer" as bad programming, then yes, it was bad programming. :-) Of course I fixed the problem before delivering to the client.